# Delphi - Getting property values with GetPropValue()

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi's `GetPropValue()` function to get values ​​of certain properties of some objects of type `TControl`. Everything works correctly when I get simple property values ​​such as `Value`, `Opacity`, etc, but as I'm using firemonkey there are some extended properties, such as `RotationCenter`, it has `RotationCenter.X` and `RotationCenter.Y`, or even properties of text within  `TextSettings`, in these properties with sub-types I can not get the values.

In this example I get the values ​​correctly:

```
If IsPublishedProp (Component_cc, 'Value') then
  EditValue.Text: = GetPropValue (Component_cc, 'Value', true);
```

Where `Component_cc:TControl`; And is created dynamically, it can also be any type of Firemonkey component (so far everything is okay, everything works).

When I need to use the form below, it does not work.

```
If IsPublishedProp (Component_cc, 'RotationCenter.X') then
  EditRotationCenterX.Text: = GetPropValue (CC_component, 'RotationCenter.X', true);
```

Does anyone know a way to get these properties extended by this function?

Comment: You need to go deeper in the structure. Ask for `X` property the `TPosition` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the CC_component's `RotationCenter` property is actually an instance of `TPosition` class which decends from `TPersistent`.

Second, you cannot use dotted notation when calling `IsPublishedProp`.

You can use `GetObjectProp` to first retrieve the internal `TPosition` instance and then access the `X` property from there:

(Assume a simple FMX application with one form that contains a `TButton` called `Button1` and a `TEdit` called `EditRotationCenterX`.)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
   CC_component : TComponent;
   CC_component_RotationCenter : TPosition;

begin
   CC_component := Button1;

   if IsPublishedProp(CC_component, 'RotationCenter') then
      begin
         CC_component_RotationCenter := TPosition(GetObjectProp(CC_component, 'RotationCenter'));
         EditRotationCenterX.Text := CC_component_RotationCenter.X.ToString;
      end
end;
```

---

**Update, for a property of type Set:**

For a Set type property, you will need to retrieve its ordinal value using `GetOrdProp`.  This will be the array of bits that represent which elements are included in the current value.  Then, you simply test if the appropriate bit is set.  This is the method I would prefer.

Alternatively you can use `GetSetProp` which will return a text representation of the elements in the Set's current value.  For example, if the Set's value is `[TCorner.BottonLeft, TCorner.TopRight]` the you will get back the string value "TopRight,BottonLeft".  You then check to see if the name of your target element appears anywhere in the returned string.  This method is susceptible to failure if the Delphi RTL or FMX libraries are ever changed in the future.

(This example adds a `TRectangle` shape called `Rectangle1` and a `TCheckBox` called `cbCornerBottonRight` to the simple FMX App from above:)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
   CC_component : TComponent;
   CC_component_Corners : nativeint;

   CC_component_CornersAsString : string;

begin
   CC_component := Rectangle1;
   if IsPublishedProp(CC_component, 'Corners') then
      begin
         // Using this method will make your code less sensitive to 
         // changes in the ordinal values of the Set's members or      
         // changes to names of the enumeration elements.      
         //       
         CC_component_Corners := GetOrdProp(CC_component,'Corners');

         cbCornerBottonRight.IsChecked := ((1 shl ord(TCorner.BottomRight)) and CC_component_Corners) <> 0;


         // This approach may break if the names of the elements of
         // the TCorner enumeration are ever changed.  (BTW, they have
         // been in the past:  "cvTopLeft", "cvTopRight", "cvBottomLeft",
         // and "cvBottomRight" are now deprecated)
         //       
         CC_component_CornersAsString := GetSetProp(CC_component,'Corners');

         cbCornerBottonRight.IsChecked := CC_component_CornersAsString.IndexOf('BottomRight') >= 0;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Dave. I would just like to ask for more help, I understood and managed with various properties the way you taught, but with some properties, like Corners, I can not get the values. Here's how I did it:

    `if IsPublishedProp(Component_cc, 'Corners') then
      begin
        Cornersv := TCorner(GetObjectProp(Componente_cc, 'Corners'));
        ckCornerBottonRight.IsChecked := Cornersv.crBottomRight;
      end`

o erro é este: 

E2010 Incompatible types: 'Boolean' and 'TCorner'.

ckCornerBottonRight is one `TCheckbox`

Comment: The `Corners` property is not an object instance; it is of type **Set**.  It will require a quite different operation from a `TPosition` object instance.  I've updated the answer to include how you can get the value of a property of type **Set**.

Comment: Also, you may want to update your question so to include this extension concerning **Set** type properties.

Comment: Great! Works perfect! Thanks.

Comment: I believe the same principle can apply to the font, background, and border properties of the elements.

Answer (score 5):

When speaking about the old RTTI, you can do this. You need to go deeper in the structure. Ask for the **X** property the **TPosition** object:

```
var
  O: TObject;
  X: Integer;
begin
  if PropIsType(Component_cc, 'RotationCenter', tkClass) then
  begin
    O := GetObjectProp(Component_cc, 'RotationCenter');
    if Assigned(O) and PropIsType(O, 'X', tkInteger) then
      X := GetOrdProp(O, 'X');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you already have the `TPosition` object, it is not worth using RTTI to read its `X` property when you can just read it directly. `S := RotationCenter.X.ToString;`

Comment: Thank you Victoria!

Comment: @Remy, so as it's not worth using RTTI for getting `TPosition` object then :) I see your point though (no such thing as `RotationCenter` variable should be used). You may drop your comment on the answer that was copied from mine (with more unsafe typecast). I'm about to delete this one in time..